# Yaml code repetition

Tags: ansible, yaml

I have several block of code repeated all over my code, like this:

```
 - name: Retrieve VM information
  os_server_facts:
    validate_certs: False ### From this line
    api_timeout: 300
    timeout: 600
    auth:
      auth_url: "{{ cloudstack_auth_url }}"
      username: "{{ cloudstack_login }}"
      password: "{{ cloudstack_password }}"
      project_name: "{{ cloudstack_project }}"
    auth_type: v2password ### To this line
    server: "{{ vm_hostname }}"
```

Inside the same file, I could use [anchors](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/yaml/), but I don't know how to do to factorize this piece of code in differents files, any ideas ?

Comment: YAML does not provide any facilities to split a document over multiple files. However, you seem to be using some templating language (judging from the `{{ ... }}` values), so if you tell us which software stack you are using, there may be a solution outside YAML.

Comment: I am using ansible and Jinja

Comment: Effectively you are asking the same question as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48194614/2947502). Ansible can include files, but it first executes a YAML parser. Once it completes, Ansible's "execution plan" is fixed, even if you included parts of task definitions as anchors from external files, they won't be reapplied ― you can try with a dummy anchor defined in `vars` in the main playbook and a wish-to-be-overriding-one in `vars_files`. Vars files will be included by Ansible logic, but it is "too late" for them to be effective for plays or tasks.

Answer (score 1):

If you have some tasks that are used in many places you can always include these in your playbook from a common .yml file using an include.

```
- include: ../common/tasks/mytasks.yml
```

However! Ansible really want's you to use roles for this type of common task use, I would consider putting these into a very simple role and using it in your plays with include_role. It's really a better and more salable way to do this.

```
- name: Include my tasks as a role
  include_role:
    name: reusedTasks
    tasks_from: simple_role
```

Comment: Thing is the repetition is smaller than a task, in my case it is the connection data for ansible-shade, I have to pass url / login / pass / timeout for each single task... Quite heavy.